# What is the Thai man saying to Maria as he drags her through the mud?

Tags: translation, the-impossible

In the movie "The Impossible" based on the Tsunami that took place in 2004, as Maria was being dragged through the mud by the older Thai man, he keeps saying something to her over and over again. I was just curious as to what he was saying in translation please.

Answer (score 1):

A Thai here. He basically said “Stay strong. I’ve got you.”